# Are SOLR nested objects broken for multilevel nesting?

Tags: solr

I observe quite strange behaviour for multi-level nesting of SOLR objects using both SOLR 5.5.1 and SOLR 6.1.0 (SOLR Cloud to be specific, if it's important).

I consider it to be a SOLR bug. However, my experience with nested objects is limited, so, I'd really appreciate any review from more experienced folks. The steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Start clean SOLR instance and create test collection:

```
./bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt
./bin/solr create_collection -c qa -shards 2 -p 8983
```

2. Upload test data:

```
    <doc>
        <field name="id">CONTAINER_1</field>
        <field name="title">CONTAINER</field>
        <doc>
            <field name="id">CONTAINER_1_ITEM</field>
            <field name="title">META</field>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <field name="id">CONTAINER_1_PERSON</field>
            <field name="title">META</field>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <field name="id">DOC_1</field>
            <field name="title">DOCUMENT</field>
            <doc>
                <field name="id">DOC_1_ITEM</field>
                <field name="title">META</field>
            </doc>
            <doc>
                <field name="id">DOC_1_PERSON</field>
                <field name="title">META</field>
            </doc>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <field name="id">DOC_2</field>
            <field name="title">DOCUMENT</field>
            <doc>
                <field name="id">DOC_2_ITEM</field>
                <field name="title">META</field>
            </doc>
            <doc>
                <field name="id">DOC_2_PERSON</field>
                <field name="title">META</field>
            </doc>
        </doc>
    </doc>
```

3. Query for:

```
{!child of=title:DOCUMENT}id:DOC_2
```

Everything works as expected, there are 2 docs in the response:

```
    [
      {
        "id":"DOC_2_ITEM",
        "title":["META"]},
      {
        "id":"DOC_2_PERSON",
        "title":["META"]}
    ]
```

4. Query for:

```
{!child of=title:DOCUMENT}id:DOC_1
```

See strange response with 4 docs instead of 2:

```
    [
      {
        "id":"CONTAINER_1_ITEM",
        "title":["META"]},
      {
        "id":"CONTAINER_1_PERSON",
        "title":["META"]},
      {
        "id":"DOC_1_ITEM",
        "title":["META"]},
      {
        "id":"DOC_1_PERSON",
        "title":["META"]}
    ]
```

**Any ideas on what is wrong? Any ideas regarding possible workaround?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it's already said [there](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201603.mbox/%3CCANGii8f+jt3WzOuZh2yE48HkZTP4LqVzbW6OYBs2jesqP6MvLQ@mail.gmail.com%3E) try to union all enclosing parent's masks eg

**UPD**

```
{!child of='title:(DOCUMENT CONTAINER)'}id:DOC_1
```

OK ok. this different levels should be distinguishing. It will only work if you markup CONAINER_1-* docs as META_1

Comment: It worked! After I distinguished META for CONTAINER (became C_META) and META for DOCUMENT (became D_META) the requests

    +title:D_META +{!child of='title:(DOCUMENT CONTAINER)'}id:DOC_2 and 
    +title:D_META +{!child of='title:(DOCUMENT CONTAINER)'}id:DOC_1

worked as expected